# Get the nearest object by longitude and latitude and user location?

Tags: ios, core-location

I have a list of core data objects each has a longitude and latitude properties.
I have the user location from core location.

I wish to retrieve  the nearest object to the user location?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to give you an answer with code as you are only asking a general question.

But, there is a useful function in `CLLocation` called `distanceFromLocation:` which has the signature:

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

The way to do this would be to store (or create) create CLLocation objects from the locations in your Core Data store, and using the users current location you can iterate through the list of locations using this function to get the distances and then return the location with the smallest return value as the nearest location.

Comment: Thanks, its a good answer for me. not looking for code. BTW why did you remove my thanks from my question ?

Comment: @shannoga If you look around SO, you won't see many thanks and signatures, It isn't needed. There is a definitive discussion of this on Meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/154481